# How to remove or unregister a registered Custom Element?

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element

I'm currently testing the performance of Custom Elements, so I stumpled upon the need to unregister a previously registered element. I couldn't find anything about that.

I think that could probably be needed, but before I have not researched this problem in more detail I'll not do any assumptions.

I know I could do it with refreshing the page, but that's not the point here.

What I've done so far to register an element the native, spec-like way:

```
document.registerElement('my-element', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one or two discussions on google groups about unregistering elements but as far as I know no solution so far. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/31W69ZE1Wng

Comment: @PatrickHillert Has there been any update or solution on this as of yet?

Comment: @john-raymon: Nope, not really. I've searched a bit, but there's currently no solution proposed.

Comment: Is it even possible to change the definition of a custom component once it's been registered? ie. attach it to another class